# How to Get the Node IDs of an OPCUA Server from UA Expert?

Tags: python, opc-ua, opc, node-opcua

I am a noob in dealing with OPCUA and trying the python library to interface with a server. I have already established a connection with the OPCUA Expert application, and this is what a screenshot looks like.

[image]

This is how my sample python code looks like.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8
from opcua import Client
from opcua import ua
url='opc.tcp://192.168.112.94:4840'
client=Client(url=url)
somenode=client.get_node(nodeid='NS2|String/Plc/MD') # UaStringParsingError: ('Error parsing string NS2|String/Plc/MD', ValueError('not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)'))
```

So basically, what is a nodeid and how to form it from what the UA Expert shows? Does not that column bearing the same name directly give the node id? Some helps on how to find the correct node id will be appreciated.

I realise I do not even have clarity on *what* is a node, as in is it like a node in graph theory, or network routing, or something else?

Comment: Here is the Documentation of the UAExpert: https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uaexpert/1.6.3/html/first_steps.html#read 
To Create an NodeID in asyncio-opc ua  here is an example: https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/07e6df2f2ccae4eb3649fd589496d748dc22bf0a/examples/client-example.py#L38

Answer (score 3):

The syntax that python-opcua is using is "ns=2;s=String/PLC/MD", "ns=2;i=4",...

The syntax is
ns={namespace_index_no} if ommited namespace index 0 is used.

- i={numeric identifier} for example i=55
- s={string identifier} for example s=ABC
- g={uuid identifier} for example g=01108e12-d038-4591-a976-25f479008487

python-opcua is deprecated. So it's best to use opcua-asyncio, which also has a sync-wrapper, with very few changes in AP.

Comment: What is the rule to form the node string from what opcua expert shows?

Comment: A python-opcua uses the same syntax.